# add a layer of function to create a sequencing

Tags: javascript, jquery

My target is to create a sequence function where a fighter's fight should be matched after 3-4 fights after his previous fights.

Current output: (As we can see here, fighter **paul** had the fightNumber":1, paul's next match is fightNumber":2... This shouldn't happen because there must be a fightNumber gap of 2-3 fights before Paul can fight again.

```
const data = [
  {"id":"1","fighter1":"paul","fighter2":"anna","fightNumber":1},
  {"id":"2","fighter1":"jack","fighter2":"paul","fightNumber":2}, // wrong, fighter's fight should not be consecutively. there should be a gap of 2-3 fights before it can be matched again.
  {"id":"3","fighter1":"roger","fighter2":"law","fightNumber":3},
  {"id":"4","fighter1":"lee","fighter2":"law","fightNumber":4},
  {"id":"5","fighter1":"law","fighter2":"paul","fightNumber":5},
  {"id":"6","fighter1":"roger","fighter2":"anna","fightNumber":6},
  {"id":"7","fighter1":"lee","fighter2":"jack","fightNumber":7},
  {"id":"8","fighter1":"roger","fighter2":"anna","fightNumber":8},
  {"id":"9","fighter1":"lee","fighter2":"jack","fightNumber":9}
];
```

Target output: (As we can see here, paul's fight was fightnumber 1 and fightNumber 4, there's a 3 gap of fightnumber before he matched again.

```
    const new_result= [
  {"id":"1","fighter1":"paul","fighter2":"anna","fightNumber":1},
  {"id":"2","fighter1":"jack","fighter2":"paul","fightNumber":4},
  {"id":"3","fighter1":"roger","fighter2":"law","fightNumber":2},
  {"id":"4","fighter1":"lee","fighter2":"law","fightNumber":6},
  {"id":"5","fighter1":"law","fighter2":"paul","fightNumber":7},
  {"id":"6","fighter1":"roger","fighter2":"anna","fightNumber":5},
  {"id":"7","fighter1":"lee","fighter2":"jack","fightNumber":3},
  {"id":"8","fighter1":"roger","fighter2":"jack","fightNumber":8},
  {"id":"9","fighter1":"lee","fighter2":"anna","fightNumber":9}
];
```

This is the code i used

```
const usedFightNumbers = new Set();

const dataGroupedByName = data.reduce((groups, item) => {
  const groupName = item.fighter1;
  if (!groups[groupName]) {
    groups[groupName] = [];
  }

  groups[groupName].push(item);

  return groups;
}, {});

for (const groupName in dataGroupedByName) {
  dataGroupedByName[groupName].sort((a, b) => parseInt(a.fightNumber) - parseInt(b.fightNumber));
}

let result = [];
let i = 0;
while (true) {
  let done = true;
  for (const groupName in dataGroupedByName) {
    const group = dataGroupedByName[groupName];
    if (i < group.length) {
      const newItem = { ...group[i], fightNumber: String(result.length + 1) };

      while (usedFightNumbers.has(newItem.fightNumber)) {
        newItem.fightNumber = String(parseInt(newItem.fightNumber) + 0.5);
      }

      result.push(newItem);
      usedFightNumbers.add(newItem.fightNumber);
      done = false;
    }
  }
  if (done) {
    break;
  }
  i++;
}
```

```js
  const data = [
    { id: "1", fighter1: "paul", fighter2: "anna", fightNumber: 1 },
    { id: "2", fighter1: "jack", fighter2: "paul", fightNumber: 2 },
    { id: "3", fighter1: "roger", fighter2: "law", fightNumber: 3 },
    { id: "4", fighter1: "lee", fighter2: "law", fightNumber: 4 },
    { id: "5", fighter1: "law", fighter2: "paul", fightNumber: 5 },
    { id: "6", fighter1: "roger", fighter2: "anna", fightNumber: 6 },
    { id: "7", fighter1: "lee", fighter2: "jack", fightNumber: 7 },
    { id: "8", fighter1: "roger", fighter2: "anna", fightNumber: 8 },
    { id: "9", fighter1: "lee", fighter2: "jack", fightNumber: 9 },
  ];

  const usedFightNumbers = new Set();

  const dataGroupedByName = data.reduce((groups, item) => {
    const groupName = item.fighter1;
    if (!groups[groupName]) {
      groups[groupName] = [];
    }

    groups[groupName].push(item);

    return groups;
  }, {});

  for (const groupName in dataGroupedByName) {
    dataGroupedByName[groupName].sort(
      (a, b) => parseInt(a.fightNumber) - parseInt(b.fightNumber)
    );
  }

  let result = [];
  let i = 0;
  while (true) {
    let done = true;
    for (const groupName in dataGroupedByName) {
      const group = dataGroupedByName[groupName];
      if (i < group.length) {
        const newItem = { ...group[i], fightNumber: String(result.length + 1) };

        while (usedFightNumbers.has(newItem.fightNumber)) {
          newItem.fightNumber = String(parseInt(newItem.fightNumber) + 0.5);
        }

        result.push(newItem);
        usedFightNumbers.add(newItem.fightNumber);
        done = false;
      }
    }
    if (done) {
      break;
    }
    i++;
  }

  console.log(result);
```

The problem with this code is that, the gap sometimes are little like 1-2 fight number gap only and sometimes the gap is too huge that it reaches 40 fight number gap.

Is there a way where i can reconstruct this code and achieve my goal?

Thank you

Comment: Can you share what your input data look like?

Comment: I added code snippet for the reference. Thank you

Comment: your wanted example has with `id: 2` and `id: 7` with `'Jack'` only a gap of one. please add a working result.

Answer (score 3):

I managed to create the algorithm for the assigned task. Keep in mind that at some point the provided data is not enough and there are going to be no free fighters to be used in the next fight so this is why at some point the fights are getting empty and only number is provided.

it works exactly as assigned so hopefully it is going to fit your need. Feel free to ask questions about my code in case of need.

*Try the code snippet:*

```js
const data = [
  { id: "1", fighter1: "paul", fighter2: "anna", fightNumber: null },
  { id: "2", fighter1: "jack", fighter2: "paul", fightNumber: null },
  { id: "3", fighter1: "roger", fighter2: "law", fightNumber: null },
  { id: "4", fighter1: "lee", fighter2: "law", fightNumber: null },
  { id: "5", fighter1: "law", fighter2: "paul", fightNumber: null },
  { id: "6", fighter1: "roger", fighter2: "anna", fightNumber: null },
  { id: "7", fighter1: "lee", fighter2: "jack", fightNumber: null },
  { id: "8", fighter1: "roger", fighter2: "anna", fightNumber: null },
  { id: "9", fighter1: "lee", fighter2: "jack", fightNumber: null },
];

function calculatreFight() {
  const gapNumber = parseInt(document.getElementById("gapNumberInput").value);
  const tiredFightersList = [];
  const compiledIndexes = [];
  
  const fights = data.map((element, index) => {    
    const tiredFighters = tiredFightersList.slice(-gapNumber).reduce((prev, curr) => {
      curr.map(fighter => !prev.includes(fighter) ? prev.push(fighter) : null)
      return prev;
    }, []);

    let searchIndex = 0;
    while (tiredFighters.includes(data[searchIndex]?.fighter1) ||
      tiredFighters.includes(data[searchIndex]?.fighter2) ||
      compiledIndexes.includes(searchIndex)) {
      searchIndex += 1;
      if (searchIndex >= data.length) break;
    }

    tiredFightersList[index] = [data[searchIndex]?.fighter1, data[searchIndex]?.fighter2];
    compiledIndexes.push(searchIndex);

    return {
      ...data[searchIndex],
      fightNumber: index
    };
  }, []);

  console.log(fights);
}
```

```html
<label>Select how many gap fights should a fighter have: </label>
<select name="gap" id="gapNumberInput">
  <option value="1">1</option>
  <option value="2">2</option>
  <option value="3">3</option>
  <option value="4">4</option>
</select>
<br>
<button onclick="calculatreFight()">Calculate</button>

<br><br><br>
<p>Remember that as bigger the gap is, the fewer possible solutions are there and so there are going to be fights that are with no figthers</p>
```

Comment: Hello. Thank you for answering. I've tried your code with mine. The problem I encountered is, the "fightNumber" is getting NULL, my target is to update/rearrange the "fightNumber" only.  

Please see the jsfiddle for reference:  https://jsfiddle.net/dying_sakura/62gveowu/3/

Thank you

Comment: Additionally, i am avoiding these results also: https://prnt.sc/Dy6iuQmCB7ex. Thank you

Comment: Okay, so correct me if I understood it wrong: You have data that already includes the `fightNumber` and you want to just fix the ones that are problematic, right? If that is the case, it will be way harder, as this will require keeping track of so many more things. Could you provide the code that generates the `data` object so I can see where that `fightNumber` initially is coming from? Thank you

Comment: Yes , you're right. Thank you that you understood it even tho my explanation is kinda messed up. Here's the updated fiddle with more data for testing: https://jsfiddle.net/dying_sakura/62gveowu/11/